How to replicate local build setup on github actions
So I have a CMake & C++ project. Locally, the projects build successfully. Also all the unit tests pass.
Locally I'm using MinGW 11.0 w64, ninja.exe, gcc.exe and g++.exe.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to setup my github actions workflow so that it would work as well.
For example, this is my current workflow:
name: CMake build and test on Windows

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

env:
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  build:
    name: build and test
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Cache dependencies and build tools
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            ${{ github.workspace }}/build/_deps
            C:/ProgramData/ccache
          key: deps-${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('CMakeLists.txt') }}
          restore-keys: |
            deps-${{ runner.os }}-

      # Install ccache (only runs if cache not found)
      - name: Install ccache
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: choco install ccache -y

      - name: Configure CMake
        run: >
          cmake -B build
          -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache
          -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}
          -S ${{ github.workspace }}

      - name: Build
        run: cmake --build build --config ${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }}

      - name: Test
        run: ctest --test-dir build -C ${{ env.BUILD_TYPE }} -L WW --verbose

which unfortunately fails. And as much as I would like to know why it fails, I don't.
The logs reported by the github actions are massive (more than 55k lines), and after using a search function I was unable to find any line with error C or fatal error or LNK.
There is certainly something different from my local setup, because locally all works.
So I guess the question is twofold:

how can I replicate my local setup?
how I can debug 55k lines of logs to finally figure out the problem it?


can try to check the GitHub Actions runner environment documentation to confirm. further, install act to simulate the GitHub Actions environment locally before submitted to github actions workflow.

what is the actual reported error?

"after using a search function I was unable to find any line with error" Web search on github actions tends to only search on visible text :-/. You have to search inside the raw log.
